# What is wrong this simple history script?

Tags: bash, sed

I am missing something really simple I think:

```
$ cat hs.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
history | grep -i $1
echo $#
exit
$
```

here is output:

```
$ ./history_search sed
sed
1
$
```

Trying to create a script which I can use in form of './hs.sh sed' to search for all sed commands in history. I can create an alias using this which works fine, but not this script.

Here is the alias:

```
alias hg='history | grep -i $1'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I strongly counsel you against experimenting on Unix systems as user `root`.  You can wreck the entire system with an accidental typo as root, but you are largely protected from damaging the system if you are not root.  History is a bad area for experimentation too; if you accidentally run `rm -fr .` instead of some other command that you intended, you can wreak havoc again.  Do make sure you've got good backups if you decide to continue working as root.

Answer (score 2):

Interactive shells have history; scripted shells do not have history.  You can only ask for history from an interactive shell, which is why the alias works but the script does not.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this as a shell script, it spawns a new shell that has no history.

Try running it in the same shell like this:

```
source ./history_search see
```

and it should work.

Comment: If you source a script where the last line is `exit`, you will probably not be very happy.  That might easily be argued to be a bug in the script — normally a harmless one, but not if the script might be sourced.

Comment: I will try this soon, I don't know about some of the arguments given above.